# Multidex transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug Failed

Tags: android, jar, proguard, android-multidex

I am developing Android library. When My Client(Application developer) applied my Jar file, it is shown error message.
Build is normal working, But When I run(playButton) App in Android Studio, it is occurred.
The error message shown like below :
    Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't read [/Users/VSSCP_KYOSEON/Documents/Work/Android/A/B/app/build/intermediates/transforms/jarMerging/debug/jars/1/1f/combined.jar] (Can't process class [com/a/b/VSFunctionActivity.class] (Unknown verification type [88] in stack map frame))

This is my Application Gradle Code :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.a.b"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile project(':ChartLib')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile files('libs/vs_sat_sdk.jar')
```

}

My Jar file is vs_sat_sdk.jar. It is applied to proguard.
I already applied Android Multidex guide. https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html But I failed to execute.

I have normal operation situation.
1. I apply proguard in My jar file. and When minSdkVersion is over 21, it is normal operation. But When minSdkVersion is under 21, it is shown failed.
2. If My jar file doesn't applied proguard, regardless of minSdkVersion, it is normal operation.

please let me know about your solution.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the jar file has been processed by a tool that does not correctly update the StackMapFrame attribute.

Actually, StackMapFrame attributes are not needed for Android development, so you could instruct ProGuard to not create it and it might solve your issue. Add the following to your configuration when applying ProGuard to your library:

```
-dontpreverify
```

Comment: Thank you. I already set -dontpreverify. But The same problem occurs. I fixed this issue. After setting -dontoptimize, working is fine.